# Why no subject after “as”?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement, subjects

1. Please correct me, but does **as** function as a conjunction here? I already tried [i](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13746/8712), [ii](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/as-it-is-and-as-is-as-as-a-conjunction-and-a-pronoun), and [iii](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90800/as-is-customary-vs-as-it-is-customary).

> Page 3: In any event it might be said that Hart ‘won’ the debate in the sense that it was his
>   infl uence that led to the passing of the 1960s legislation liberalising the law on abortion, prostitution, homosexuality, and abolishing capital punishment. However *such issues* can still arise – as **was** seen in the Brown case, considered later, and the ongoing issue of the ‘rights’ relating to assisted suicide...

`2.` Why no subject here? Isn't the subject *such issues*, which implies
"such issues can still arise – as **they were** seen in the Brown case..."?

> Page 43: ...the new coalition Justice Minister is the
>   extremely experienced MP Kenneth Clarke QC, although his experience may not save
>   the legal system from the consequences of the comprehensive spending review, as **was**
>   made only too evident in the announcement in November 2010 that the whole of the
>   civil legal aid system was to be fundamentally restructured, not to say cut (see further at
>   chapter 14 below)

(Question 3 has been posted separately) `4.` Why no subject here? What'd be the subject?

`5.` Are there any terms that describe the ideas or issues in this entire post?

Source: *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper. I myself bolded and italicised.

Answer (score 3):

1. You may call *as* a subordinating conjunction, **as** is the case in traditional grammar, or a preposition, **as** is the case in *CGEL*. It doesn't really matter what you call it.
2. The subject of the *as* clause is not *such issues* but the entire superordinate clause. What was seen was not the issues but their arising. You might paraphrase

   > That such issues can arise was seen in [&c] *OR*
   >   In [&c] it was seen that such issues can arise.

   An explicit subject within the subordinate clause is not required; when an explicit subject is absent the construction is understood to take a preceding clause or constituent as its subject. The same phenomenon may be observed with other constructions:

   > 1.Bill wants Susan to go to the party.
   >   2.Bill wants to go to the party.

   In 2, Bill is the subject of both *want* and *go*, so we do not need to say *Bill wants Bill to go to the party.*
3. The verb is singular because its subject is singular.
4. In the 'p.43' quotation, likewise, the subject is the preceding clause *his experience ... review*. What was made evident was the inability of Mr. Clarke's experience to save the legal system.
5. These are *comparative constructions* (like *as...as*, *same...as*, *such...as*) of a special kind: the initial *as* or *same* or *such* is omitted because what is being compared is things which are equal. The phenomenon expressed in the head clause is 'like' or the *same as* what is *seen* or *evident* (or, in my 1., *the case*) in the subordinate clause.

Comment: +1. Thank you. Regarding 2 and 4, Would you please explain why there's no subject after **as**?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as a comment? I don't apprehend how it answers my questions.