# Can clauses be singular and/or plural?

Tags: clauses, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

> Page 3: ... However *such issues* can still arise – as **was** seen in the Brown case, considered later, and the ongoing issue of the ‘rights’ relating to assisted suicide...

`3.` This was originally question 3 [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32146/8712): *such issues* is plural, so why's the verb (after 'as') singular?  Is this verb called the copula?

User StoneyB kindly replied:

> The verb is singular because its subject is singular.

Is "*such issues* can still arise" "the entire [superordinate clause](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/super.htm)" in StoneyB's words? I do accept this as the subject, but how can clauses have grammatical number? What does this mean?

Comment: A clause has a **default** person and number of *3rd person singular*. E.g. "[What they want] **is** [peace and quiet]", the clause "What they want" is treated as being a 3rd person singular subject for subject/verb agreement in the matrix clause. (Edited: Er, "What they want" might be ambiguous, either a subordinate interrogative clause or a noun phrase.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clauses do not have inherent number, but when a clause is employed under the category of an NP<sup>†</sup> it must be treated as either singular or plural. A single clause so employed is treated as a singular entity; two or more coordinated clauses so employed are treated as a plural entity.

> That John is hungry **is** **an** effect of his fast.
>   That John is hungry, that he is feeble and that he is incoherent **are** effect**s** of his fast.

---

<sub><sup>†</sup>An 'NP' is not the same thing as a 'noun phrase'. A noun phrase is a phrase headed by a noun, while an 'NP' (pronounced En-Pee) is a phrase which plays certain (not all) syntactic roles typical of a noun or noun phrase. Thus a clause (which is headed by a verb) cannot be a noun phrase, but it can be (as in these examples) an NP.</sub>

Comment: Thank you effusively for your detail. I apologise, but am glad to be enlightened now! Would you mind moving your comment into your answer?